# CSS not getting included in sub directories

Tags: html, css

I have the following directory structure:[image]

I have put up a header which is going to come across all my webpages and the content is in header.html.

header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_styles.css"></link>

    <script>     
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var pathname = this.location.pathname;

        if( pathname.indexOf( 'index' ) > -1 )
        {
           $("#homepage").addClass( "active" );
        }
        else if( pathname.indexOf( 'java_archive' ) > -1 ) )
        {
            $("#javapage").addClass( "active");
        }

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"> <!-- PavanD: navbar-static-top helps in removing the rounded navbar.-->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#5F5F5F;"> <!--505050 can also be considered -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id=headerEntries class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="homepage"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONCEPTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
        <li id="javapage"><a href="java_archives/index.html">JAVA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ORACLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DATA STRUCTURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REACH US</a></li>          
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Programming Pages</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_styles.css"></link>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#headerContent").load("header.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="headerContent"></div>

<div class="container"> <!-- PavanD: Evaluate between container-fluid and container.-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 img-rounded" style="background-color:#F1F1F1;">
        <!-- PavanD: img-rounded helps in rounding the intro information -->

<h3 class="text-center">Welcome to the site!</h3>

<p>Getting placed into an established Software Company during Campus Recruitments is the dream of most Engineering students. All it needs is demonstrating technical expertise related to Computer Programming.</p>

<p>Computer Programming is a promising area and has great scope for opportunities. It is often misunderstood as being quite difficult. This is especially true for students who are not
from Computer Science or Information Technology braches. Also, students from Computer Science or Information Technology tend to stick to the programmes which they have had in their programming lab and Engineering curriculum itself is a bit hectic that most do not find time or guidance
to explore these areas. Moreover, there can be multiple solutions to the same problem. All these are very simple yet important things that ultimately help a student in building his technical expertise.</p>

<p>The content of this website is written taking into consideration the above fact. This wesite helps students receive programming guidance in an unorthodox way which is more closer to a students perspective and thus helps the student grasp the concept instead of having to by-heart it.</p>

<p>As it stands now, the website has two broad categories. 
        <li><b>BEGINNERS</b></li><li><b>INTERMEDIATE</b></li></p>        
<p>Students can always post their questions by visting the Reach Me page.</p>

<p class="text-right">Happy Programming,</p>
<p class="text-right">Webmaster.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>    


</body>
</html>
```

My java_archives/index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#headerContent").load("../header.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
     <div id="headerContent"></div>
      <p>Reached Java Page!.</p>
  </body> 
</html>
```

I am noticing a difference in the way the header gets rendered in the **root/index.html** and the **root/java_archives/index.html**. The difference that I want to convey can be observed in the below screen shot:

[image]

Basically, I feel that my css in css folder is not getting picked during the evaluation at java_archives/index.html

My root/css/custom_styles.css looks like this:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav{

}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff; /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they load. */
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #000000; /* PavanD: When you click the top menu items, they have to be rendered in black.*/
    color: #ffffff; /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they are clicked. We want it to be white so this.*/
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #FFF;
}

li{
    font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:normal;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:10px !important; padding-bottom:10px !important;}
.navbar {min-height:40px !important}
```

Is there something that I am missing here?. I am fairly new to CSS and so any inputs would be helpful.

Thanks,
Pavan.

EDIT: The following is with  addition to java_archives/index.html.
[image]
In the root/index.html case, which is the top one, I can see my custom_styles.cxx overwriting the one from bootstrap. But in the second case, my stylesheet getting overwritten. And I am not able to comprehend why it is happening like that.

Comment: I think you are missing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom_styles.css"></link>` in your **root/java_archives/index.html** file

Comment: Please check the edit section of the question. I can see the css getting overwritten, but not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Have a look at '<base>' tag. It may be helpful for you. It basically makes all relative paths start from a path you choose.

Comment: can you check / attach screenshots of your network tab as well? might give you some clues as to how CSS files (in what order etc.) are being loaded in your java_archives folder

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the missing `css/custom_styles.css` in your **root/java_archives/index.html** file....

With relative paths, such as `css/custom_styles.css`, the browser will look for `java_archives/css/custom_styles.css` instead of trying to find it in the root of your server.

You will need to either update the the path for the subfolder to `../css/custom_styles.css` or use a fixed path `/css/custom_styles.css`

Comment: I did add the line as suggested. But still I am not seeing few things like the black highlighting part when I hover across a header link which I can see in root/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your **root/java_archives/index.html** code like below..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/custom_styles.css"></link>

        <script> 
        $(function(){
          $("#headerContent").load("../header.html"); 
        });
        </script> 
      </head> 
      <body> 
         <div id="headerContent"></div>
          <p>Reached Java Page!.</p>
      </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Please check ythe question again as I have updated it after adding this line. I can see the css getting overwritten. But I cannot understand why this is happening.